# Word boundaries on git log --grep

Tags: regex, git

I'm trying to identify commits related to a reported issue, and for that I'm using `git log --grep=<Issue Id>` to accomplish that. However, if I try -for example- to locate commits for ISSUE-5, I got the following after executing `git log --grep=ISSUE-5` :

- Commit for ISSUE-5
- Commit for ISSUE-50
- Commit for ISSUE-501

Since `--grep` is supposed to support regular expressions, I tried using word boundaries like `git log --grep='\bISSUE-5\b'` and `git log --grep='\<ISSUE-5\>'` without obtaining any match.

What's the word boundaries format supported in `git log`?

**PS:** If it is relevant, I'm executing the commands from Git Bash installed on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: are yo saying `git log --grep='\bISSUE-5\b'` is not returning anything?

Comment: You're right, is working properly now @Saleem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have following simulated commit long

```
commit f9cdc8ed5463e4b73ecf63ef57c889d7e2603a6b
Author: XXXX <xxxx@yahoo.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 27 15:34:51 2016 -0400

    Commit for ISSUE-501

commit 3e0e85e97696fb74030dca9d4ec86e4d56146dc1
Author: YYYY <xxxx@yahoo.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 27 15:34:28 2016 -0400

    Commit for ISSUE-50

commit fa51233ee6410566fe4469e3c962063af51092b7
Author: ZZZZZ <zzzzz@yahoo.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 27 15:33:48 2016 -0400

    Commit for ISSUE-5
```

When I try `git log --grep='\bISSUE-5\b'`, I get

```
Author: ZZZZZ <zzzzz@yahoo.com>
Date:   Sun Mar 27 15:33:48 2016 -0400

    Commit for ISSUE-5
```